# Chef Ohai: how to use newly installed Ruby with gem_package

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Using `chef` I have a simple recipe that installs a gem, example:

```
gem_package "passenger" do
  version node['passenger']['version']
end
```

I also want to install ruby with another cookbook, it might be Ruby 1.9.3 for some servers and Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7 for others. So I thought I could use `gem_binary` and `ohai` to do this, like this:

```
gem_package "passenger" do
  version node['passenger']['version']
  gem_binary "#{languages['ruby']['bin_dir']/gem}"
end
```

But then the problems start, because `languages['ruby']` is not changed when a new ruby is installed. Ruby Enterprise installs into `/opt/ruby-enterprise` and adds itself to `PATH` via `/etc/profile.d/ree.sh` but that is not being picked up by `ohai` during the same run, but gets picked up in the next run.

In the first run, `ohai` says that `languages['ruby']` is installed in `/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/ruby` when used with `vagrant` and `chef_solo` provision. And the passenger gem is installed into the wrong ruby.

How can I make `ohai` recognize the newly installed ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I am working with RVM which has the same problem. There I usually hardcode the path to the gem binary and leave the last bit as an attribute.

E.G.

something like

```
  5   node["rvm"]["rubies"].each do |ruby|
  6     gem_package "[#{ruby}]-passenger" do
  7       package_name "passenger"
  8       version node[:passenger][:version]
  9       gem_binary "/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem-#{ruby}"
 10       options "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
 11     end
 12   end
```

Alternatively we have used `bash` blocks and sourced the appropriate file. Note when using bash blocks only the last thing in the block will be used to determine success, it is often wise to chain them with `&&`

Comment: isn't there some way to update the ohai automatic attribute `languages['ruby']['gem_bin']` to look at the newly installed gem binary?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a way to reload ohai attributes during running chef recipe:

You need to use ohai resource:

```
ohai "reload" do
  action :reload
end
```

See more here: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Ohai

Comment: problem with this is that chef compiles everything at the very start, and doing ohai:reload will not affect the already compiled resources - so it is still using the old gem binary.

Comment: I got your problem, may be this one resource can help you: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-RubyBlock
  
As resource description state: `Ruby Block

The ruby_block resource can be used to execute a bit of Ruby code during a run. Ruby code in ruby_block resources is evaluated with other resources during convergence, whereas Ruby code outside ruby_block resources is evaluated before other resources, during recipe evaluation (compilation).`

Comment: Again, as you quoted, all references to languages['ruby']['gem_binary'] outside the ruby block are evaluated at the very start, and can't be changed with the code written inside the ruby_block.

Comment: don't reference to languages['ruby']['gem_binary'] outside the ruby block then :) Do it inside.

Comment: Other cookbooks which want to install gems using a gem_binary don't have ruby blocks, do you suggest to go and change dozens of off-the-shelf cookbooks to use ruby_blocks instead of `gem_package`?

Comment: Hello Evgeny, you need to notify your ruby block with ohai "reload" from resource where you installing ruby. See example of notifing ruby block here: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Attributes#Attributes-CookbookAttributeFileOrdering